# React Native + Redux: Where to put functions for 3rd party libraries?

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm creating an ecommerce app that uses a geolocation library (https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation).

I have an `orderState`:

```
const ordersInitState = {
  lineItems: [],
  status: ORDER_STATUSES.AWAITING_CHECKOUT,
};

const ordersReducer = (prevState=ordersInitState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    ...
    case actions.ORDERS.REMOVE_ITEM:
      const lineItems = [...prevState.lineItems];
      const indexToRemove = action.payload;
      lineItems.splice(indexToRemove, 1);

      const status = lineItems.length > 0 ? prevState.status : ORDER_STATUSES.AWAITING_CHECKOUT;

      return {
        ...prevState,
        status,
        lineItems,
      };
    default:
      return prevState;
  }
}

export default ordersReducer;
```

As you can see, the client is allowed to remove items from their cart. If they end up removing everything, their order status will reset. If they do end up emptying their cart (`lineItems.length === 0`) I want to also run a simple line from the geolocation library:

`BackgroundGeolocation.removeGeofence("blah");`

Where would I put this? It feels wrong to do it in the reducer because it has nothing to do with state. It also isn't specific to one particular component, so putting it in one of my components doesn't make sense.

I'm still a bit new to redux so I'm not sure where to put non-state related methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The often used name for what you are looking for is called "side effects" middleware. In the abstract, you want to cause an effect in an external system (in this case, the geolocation library), when the application state changes.

There are many libraries for this use case. Some of the more popular ones are [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) and [redux-loop](https://github.com/redux-loop/redux-loop). They are both good tools and help give structure to managing complicated side effects, but both come with a significant conceptual overhead, and should only be used when really needed.

If you want a quick and simple solution, you can create a plain JavaScript module that `subscribe`s to your store changes and executes the side effects for you:

```
import store from '../your/redux/store;

let previousCount = 0;
store.subscribe(() => {
  const count = store.getState().orders.lineItems.length;
  if (count === 0 && previousCount > 0) {
    // someone just emptied the cart, so execute side-effect
    BackgroundGeolocation.removeGeofence("blah");
  }  
  previousCount = count;
});
```

And then if you find yourself needing this type of solution repeatedly, you can reach for one of the libraries mentioned above.

Comment: Awesome!! didn't know this existed! Thanks a lot